# In NetSuite I am getting the error "Sublist inventorynumber field inventorynumber is not a subrecord field"

Tags: netsuite

We do not have inventoryassignment set up. I am trying to create a new returnauthorization record. I can attach the item but I can't seem to update the fields in the item or populate the inventorynumber with the serial number. If you populate the field on the form by hand it works, but I can't get it to work in the restlet.

When trying to populate the inventorynumber I get the error "Sublist inventorynumber field inventorynumber is not a subrecord field".

```
// create new rma record
var rmarecord=nlapiCreateRecord('returnauthorization');
rmarecord.setFieldValue('customform','116'); // form is RMA
rmarecord.setFieldValue('department', '55'); 
rmarecord.setFieldValue('class', '56'); 
rmarecord.setFieldValue('location', '20'); 
rmarecord.setFieldValue('otherrefnum', datain.ponumber);
rmarecord.setFieldValue('custbody2', datain.rma);
rmarecord.setFieldValue('custbody3', datain.problemdesc);
rmarecord.setFieldValue('entity', datain.customerid);

// Select Line Item
rmarecord.selectNewLineItem('item');
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', itemrecordid);
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate', '0');
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', '0');
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', '1');
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'pricelevel', '0'); // Custom

var inventorydetailrecord = rmarecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorynumber');

inventorydetailrecord.selectNewLineItem('inventorynumber');
inventorydetailrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventorynumber', 'inventorynumber', datain.serial);
inventorydetailrecord.commitLineItem('inventorynumber');
inventorydetailrecord.commit(); 

rmarecord.commitLineItem('item');

var rmaid = nlapiSubmitRecord(rmarecord,false,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**
I have just noticed that you have written that you not using inventoryassignment.
In this case, you don't have the inventory detail subrecord, instead, try to set values to a field called "serialnumbers" :

```
rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'serialnumbers',datain.serial);
```

Anyhow, if you will decide to use inventoryassignment, please find below the explanation regarding the inventory detail subrecord.

The subrecord field id is "inventorydetail"

The sublist id inside the inventory detail sub record is called "inventoryassignment".

The serial number field id inside the inventory assignment sublist is "receiptinventorynumber".

Please see the code snippet below in order to update the SN inside the subrecord:

```
var inventorydetailrecord = rmarecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
inventorydetailrecord.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventorydetailrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'receiptinventorynumber', datain.serial);
inventorydetailrecord.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventorydetailrecord.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Taking out the inventorydetail stuff and adding the below line worked.

    rmarecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'serialnumbers', datain.serial);

I actually had this same line in my code minus the 's' at the end of serialnumber. I was so close.

Comment: NO Problem, happy to help.
Please mark this answer as the correct answer to that post will appear as resolved for future searches.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

inventorydetailrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventorynumber', 'inventorydetail', datain.serial);