# SuiteScript 1.0 - Set pricelevel on line items

Tags: netsuite, suitescript1.0

I've been trying to save my price level for a quote (estimate) in NetSuite using SuiteScript 1.0 (I want it to be a "Custom" price level, not "Base Price (exc. GST)").

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599696/in-netsuite-i-am-getting-the-error-sublist-inventorynumber-field-inventorynumbe) in StackOverflow, but trying that same method doesn't seem to set the price level for me and it always gets created as "Base Price (exc. GST)" regardless of what I try.

I was wondering if anyone might have managed to get this working using SuiteScript 1.0?

Here are two example approaches that I've tried (imagining there's a for loop around both):

1.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++) {
     quote.selectNewLineItem('item');
     quote.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', myId);
     quote.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', myQuantity);
     quote.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate', '100');
     quote.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'priceLevel', '-1'); // Custom price
     quote.commitLineItem('item');
}
```

2. 

```
for (var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++) {
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', i, myId);
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, myQuantity);
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'rate', i, '100');
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'pricelevel', i, '-1'); // Custom price
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One potential issue is that your Netsuite account needs to be configured to allow custom price levels. Can you set the custom price level in the GUI?

Comment: Also what type of script are you trying to do this in? Client? User Event? Scheduled?

Comment: I can set them in the GUI, so hopefully that would mean that we're allowed to set them in the script too. I'd like to do this in a RESTlet, so I can kick it off at any point that it's needed. Does the syntax above seem to be correct though? I can't quite figure out what I've been doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

So I had some help and was able to figure out what was causing the issue.

In my case, I was using 'pricelevel', but what I really should have been using was 'price' (see: https://1325230.app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/estimate.html)

Then, setting that to '-1' seemed to do the trick. Shoutout to the intuitive naming in NetSuite but...at least now the script is up and running. Sample code below for anyone else who might come across this issue in the future:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++) {
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', i, myId);
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, myQuantity);
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'amount', i, '100');
     quote.setLineItemValue('item', 'price', i, '-1'); // Custom price
}
```